# Am I hashing passwords correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, libsodium

My current project is my first in Node.js (also using MongoDB, Mongoose, and Express, if it matters), and being easily distracted, I have fallen down the rabbit hole of crypto while deciding how to handle user authentication. (No other encryption is needed on this project).

Following the pattern on [this page](http://devsmash.com/blog/password-authentication-with-mongoose-and-bcrypt) (pattern, not code - I am having problems with installing node.bcrypt but not with node-sodium) and [also this page](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing) my process is

1. new user submits password over https
2. the schema generates a salt
3. schema hashes a concatenation of the password and salt
4. schema stores the salt and the password with the user information

Now I don't know if this my personal deficiency, but I am having trouble following [the libsodium documentation](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/password_hashing/the_argon2i_function.html). [node-sodium](https://github.com/paixaop/node-sodium) does not provide any additional information for hashing (though it does have an example for encryption).

This is the code I want to use to generate the hash:

```
let buf = new Buffer(sodium.crypto_pwhash_STRBYTES);
sodium.randombytes_buf(buf, sodium.crypto_pwhash_STRBYTES);
let salt = buf.toString();
let preBuffer = "somePass" + salt;
let passwordBuf = Buffer.from(preBuffer);
let hash = sodium.crypto_pwhash_str(passwordBuf, sodium.crypto_pwhash_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE, sodium.crypto_pwhash_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE);
```

So the question is two parts. Is this a good process, and is the code appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

I've used the `scrypt-for-humans` package in the past for exactly this reason.

https://github.com/joepie91/scrypt-for-humans

Scrypt is a very secure hashing library and this higher level wrapper makes it hard for you to mess anything up. It's also specifically designed for securely hashing passwords so thats a positive as well :)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the best password hashing algorithm is [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2). There is a module called [secure-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-password) written by [Emil Bay](https://github.com/emilbayes). He talks more about cryptographically secure password hashing and best practices [on this podcast](http://www.the-gnomad.com/podcasts/keeping_passwords_safe_in_2018). Here is a snippet of what he said about [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).

> Normally when you lay out a threat model, perfect security from a mathematical point of view is almost never practical. (In cryptography, can be referred to as perfect secrecy which means, even if you have an enormous computer the size of the universe, it doesn’t matter how big it is, you can never break the security, but that’s not really practical in the real world.) Instead you go for something called computational secrecy. Which means you can break this, but it will cost you too much money and take too much time.
>
> The goal of these hash functions is to make it so expensive to brute force these algorithms that there would be no point in trying. In a threat model, you know that you are not going to get perfect security but can you make it so expensive for your adversary to attack you.
>
> [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) has two parameters that make it immune to large scale GPU attacks. You can control how much memory the function is allowed to use, and you can control how much computation time taken to make a hash. A CPU usually has a lot of memory but a few cores. A GPU has very little memory but thousands of cores. [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) dials up a lot of memory that you can only do about 4 or 8 simultaneous [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) hashes on a single GPU which makes it too expensive to try and crack. In [secure-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-password), I’ve taken the values that Frank Denise who made sodium which it’s built on figured out. It’s within the bounds of an interactive service like a website can afford to create reasonable security without slowing down. To hash a password, you need about 16 or 32 Mb of memory and those parameters can be controlled in [Argon 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).

Answer (score -4):

Personally I've used [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) and I do exactly the same 4 steps you are doing right now (after checking a few conditions 7 chars pass, one symbol, one number... ). I'll share the code using crypto.

```
var salt =rand(160, 36);    
var salted_pass = salt + password;
var token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex'); // I even generate a token for my users
var hashed_password = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salted_pass).digest("hex");
```

**EDIT**: **Warning** this is not a completly safe method of doing it, as it may turn predictibly. Refer to comments below which explain why it is not a good method.

Comment: This code is __completely broken__ from a security point of view. A single pass of SHA512 is __not__ sufficient for password hashing, and is absolutely __not__ equivalent to using an actual password hash. Without knowing where your `rand` function comes from, I also suspect that it doesn't provide cryptographically secure random values, and is therefore also insecure. See also here: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016

Comment: @Alan [Recommended reading](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).

Comment: @SvenSlootweg thanks for the review. This was my first attempt to hashing, and I followed a tutorial I found somewhere. Can't find it again, but Scott's article helped me understand a little bit. I'll edit my answer with a warning.